# Polymer 1.x + Firebase 2.x: Firebase data does not load on first render after login

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-polymer, polymerfire

On the ***first load*** of the page after a user login event, I want to populate the `items` property with a set of objects stored in my Firebase.

**A** achieves my desired behavior.

A

```
<firebase-query
    id="query"
    ...
    path="users/[[user.uid]]/widgets"
    data="{{items}}">
</firebase-query>
```

**B** does not.

B

```
<firebase-query
    id="query"
    ...
    path="widgets"
    data="{{items}}">
</firebase-query>
```

When using **B**, I expect to see the `items` object populate, but instead the `items` object is null. However, if I refresh the browser manually (without logging out) the element behaves as expected. However, if I log out (then refresh *while* logged out), the problem reappears until I reload again. If I only log out then log back in the problem does not reappear due, I think, in part [to the fact the app does not *reset* as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40950522/1640892).

Why does **A** work? But not **B**? And what modifications must I make to **B** to get it to work? (Because I want to store the `widgets` from the `root/widgets/` path and not have to store that detail under the `users/...` path.

#### Previous Unsuccessful Attempts

My current (unproven) theory is that the in the case of **B** (when the URL is constant/static, i.e., `widgets/`) `firebase-query` gets involved in some sort of *race condition*; and only fetches the data after some lifecycle event and doesn't attempt to re-fetch the data. On the other hand, the `firebase-query` *does* attempt to re-fetch when the path is dynamically updated based on the databinding in the `path` attribute (i.e., `path="users/[[user.uid]]/widgets"`). Is this theory correct? Or is there some other cause? Do I need to imperatively fetch the data after some event? If so, how can I accomplish all this?

I have tried the following ideas without success.

C

```
user: {
  type: Object,
  notify: true,
  observer: '_userChanged',
},

_userChanged: function() {
  this.$.query.path = 'widgets';
  var items = this.$.query.ref.child('widgets');
  this.set('items', items);
},
```

D

```
<firebase-query
    id="query"
    ...
    path="[[path]]"
    data="{{items}}">
</firebase-query>

<script>
...
  properties: {
    path: {
      type: String,
      value: function() {
        return 'widgets';
      },
    }
  },
...
</script>
```

Also, on the Polymer Slack Site, @will-in-china says:

> I have had problems with the data loading the first time, I found that if i don't have more than one reference to the same path, i dont get this issue.

I'm not sure what that means in this context as I only have one reference in my element (and app) to the path `path="widgets"` inside a `firebase-query` element.

Comment: have u rule out the localhost issues related to http /cache on the fetch?  i dont think it would be that but , at least put aside the standard issue of making sure your browser is config'd so that caching is not throwing an additional wrench in things.

Comment: is there any XHR code associated with the Fetch? I say that because i think in the template code you can manually fire/retrigger the Fetch on [[items]] instead of rely on the documented lifecyle observers on bound objects?

Comment: @RobertRowntree: Strike my earlier comment. I have not found a solution yet. I only thought I did. No, there is no XHR code associated with the fetch. Can you please explicate your idea in your second comment? And how would I rule out localhost issues? I mean, I cleared the cache but is there anything else I can do beyond that? The problem still persists.

Comment: u might go over to the 'slack'  at : https://polymer-slack.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

i dont think this is your specific issue but it may be similar in that after a login -> setNewRoute(nextPage)  i did not get a render and i changed the subsequent template ( Iron-Ajax ) to fire manually rather than via the observer.

```
  loggon: function parseLogin(user, password) {
...

     Parse.User.logIn(_user, _pass).then(function() {
      page('/channels');

---
channels.render ...

      _render: function() {
        console.log('_render');
        this.$.get_channlinq.headers = hdr;
        //xhr params
        var body = this._setQry(this.params.channelId);
        this.$.get_channlinq.body = JSON.stringify(body);
        //fetch , load , template will render
        this.$.get_channlinq.generateRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

> "When using A, I expect to see the items object populate, but instead
>   the items object is null. However, if I refresh the browser manually
>   (without logging out) the element behaves as expected. However, if I
>   log out (then refresh while logged out), the problem reappears until I
>   reload again."

I'm seeing similar behavior in my app. In my case, it is related to firebase-auth and firebase-query race conditions. In my case,

1. When I login, the firebase-auth is firing at the same time/after firebase-query. In this case, my query is rejected because of invalid permission - I am querying before being authenticated.
   Error log excerpt:

   > "detail: Error: permission_denied at /parents: Client doesn't have
   >       permission to access the desired data.    …, type: "error", target:
   >       firebase-query ....
   >   firebase-query does not retry after authentication is complete. I don't know if this is a bug.
2. When I refresh after logging in, since I am already authenticated, the query is successful.

To debug this issue, I added a on-error handler to print out the permissions. To get around this issue, I am using the disabled property. When the page is first loaded, all queries are disabled. Only when authentication is successful, I toggle "disabled" at which point queries fire successfully.

```js
signIn: function(){
  var email = this.user.email;
  var password = this.user.password;
  this.$.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
     .then(function(response){
  self.disabled = false;
  // console.log('signin', response);
  })
 .catch(function(error){
  console.log('auth-element:signIn error is', error.detail);
  })
 .then(function(){
    // call other functions
 });
 },
handleError: function(error){
  console.log('error message', error.detail.message);
},
```

```html
<firebase-query
   id = "query"
   app-name="my-app"
   path = "/shoeboxes"
   data = "{{datauid}}"
   on-error="handleError"
   disabled="{{disabled}}">
</firebase-query>
```

Hope this helps. Basically, I'm finding that with polymer and firebase, promises are better than automagical bindings...

Answer (score -1):

I'm coming late but I resolve this using dom-if condition if user
this prevent make a request if no are an user authenticate